# Clean VIP with Delegate Pattern

Tags: ios, swift, clean-architecture, viper-architecture

I am new to Clean VIP Architecture and I am struggling with its entry point.

(I am only putting some bit of code)

ViewController

```
protocol Delegate: class { 
   func execute()
}

class TitlesViewController:UIViewController {
   weak var delegate: Delegate?

   func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()
         delegate.execute()
      }

}
```

Configurator

```
class TitlesConfigurator {

static func configureModule(viewController: TitlesViewController) {
    let interactor = Interaction()
    
    viewController.delegate = interactor
    
   }
}
```

In AppDelegate

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    
    let titlesViewController = TitlesViewController()
    let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: titlesViewController)
    TitlesConfigurator.configureModule(viewController: titlesViewController)
    
    window = UIWindow()
    window?.rootViewController = navigationController
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    
    return true
}
```

Now Issue that I am facing is that there is no reference of `interactor` outside of `TilesConfigurator` and `delegate` is `weak` which means its total `arc` is 0. It results in `delegate = nil` inside `viewDidLoad`

How can I improve or fix this issue in my architecture.

P.S: I don't think its good practice to make a strong reference of delegate inside `ViewController`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delegate shouldn't be `weak` here

```
var delegate: Delegate?
```

As there is one part that's `weak` which is `let interactor = Interaction()` so no retain cycles will occur

Comment: It was by mistake. I have updated. but it does not solve the issue of `arc`

Comment: I know the issue will be solved if i don't keep delegate weak. but general saying is delegates should be weak as it can cause retain cycle. Is there any way to justify that in this case delegate should not be weak?

Comment: `let interactor = Interaction()` is weak as it's a local variable and to check that track `deinit` call inside the vc